# Instagram : Access token validity

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, instagram

I want to check whether the access token which i receive after authenticating and redirecting to the app is valid after some times.

Consider i have an access token generated using this [URL](https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI&response_type=token&scope=SCOPE).

According to the document the access token is valid forever, and in case if the user changes his password or else if he revokes the access in future, the access token get invalidated automatically,

How do i check whether the access token which is valid for that instant of time?

Comment: The access token of will never change for instagram. Even if the user revokes the access and grants later, or if he changes password the access token will be same (but access token gets invalidates in Facebook). Access token once generated for a user for that particular app will never change.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do an action with your api, for example, if the action was follow other instagram account, will return a

```
"data": {
        "outgoing_status": "requested"
    }
```

if the token was invalid, will return

```
"meta": {
    "error_message": "The access_token provided is invalid."
}
```

Comment: Ya, Thats fine.. But we do not have any api to check for the validity of it. And one good thing is the access token of will never change for instagram. even if the user revokes the access and grants later, the access token will be same. We do not have to worry about the access token at all.